# Epson L210 linux driver

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

```
I bought Epson L210 color printer and want to use it in Ubuntu 12.04.
```

when i connected that to PC, Ubuntu configured a default printer as L210 series, but it doesn't print! it just show message "printing completed" but nothing!
How i can install and use this printer in Linux Ubuntu?
    I searched Internet, but no solution! what's your solution please help me.
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try to download at the link below:
http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

Answer (score 1):

I am L210 users but i don't encounter a problem like that. Have you charge the ink before you proceed to print? you have to charge the ink for about 20min as follow to the instruction. The orange light will blink for 20 min and it will stood when the cartridge is finish to charge its ink. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

for me printing worked but scanning did not. from Epson's site, downloaded and installed `iscan-data_1.36.0-1_all.deb` and `iscan_2.30.1-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_amd64.deb` - the iscan software works just fine.